# changing/hiding error highlighting in ui elements like tabs and project view? (intellij)

Tags: java, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin, intellij-14, intellij-15

I am looking for a way to change the appearance of error highlighting in the user interface (not editor).
is there a way to change the 'waved' error underscore to a line or/and change the color of it?

highly appreciate any help, image of what i mean is below:
[ui example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wO3qU.png)

Answer (score 0):

There is no option to disable the error underlines in the editor tabs.